# Catch ajax request with java server

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, thunderbird-addon

I am trying to program a Thunderbird extension, in which I want to use features from certain java libs. But because the TB extension is written in pure javascript, I can't figure out the best way for these two technologies to communicate.

I was thinking about something like sending an ajax request from TB extension, catching it with java server code and then responding to it. I know how to work with ajax and mainly intrested in "java part" of this problem. I'm aware that, this can be solved by catching request with servlet, but I want to know if there is any solution with "pure" java.
Can anybody tell me if it is possible, or even show me some example code?

Answer (score 0):

Writing an extension isn't just writing Javascript, you'll be dealing with Mozilla's XPCOM API. There is an active Mozilla project for using Java to communicate with this API. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaXPCOM